# How to handle unintentional duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421017/t-sql-select-rows-not-equal-to-a-value-including-nulls) case today, both of top voted answers [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421071/2279200), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421073/2279200) are essentially the same. Given the timestamp I consider that the duplication is unintentional. IMHO, even if the difference is up to couple of minutes, the duplication can be interpreted as unintentional.

I think that the second (or the first) answer just adds, unwanted noise (for sure it does not add any additional value), since due to upvotes it may hide a good alternative. It is well know that not all users scroll at the bottom of the page.

I have seen this 'phenomenon' a couple of times, mostly in trivial questions, but I think the occurrences are much more.

So is there (searched I did not find anything) an 'Official' way to handle this e.g. Flag for moderator intervention? or should I leave it be?

Just out of curiosity, if already moderators handling these cases, what is the process behind, e.g. keep top-voted or accepted answer and delete its duplicates.

Comment: How would *you* propose that we handle it? Whose answer do you think we should delete? Shall we just flip a coin?

Comment: Every possible solution I am thinking, it may be considered as unfair for one of the users. The best that I can come up, is some 'function' that involves 'votes' and `accepted`. Meaning, is there is an `accepted` keep it and delete the rest, if not keep the the one with the most votes. But still I can not say that this is solid.

Comment: Why do we need to do anything about it at all?

Comment: @RobertLongson The 'why' is in my second paragraph. But generally, if we should care or not is a part of my question

Comment: My question was rhetorical.

Comment: @RobertLongson, apologies, I missed that :)

Comment: It made me chuckle that a post "How to handle unintentional duplicate answers" is itself marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the very specific type of technical Q&A we expect on Stack Overflow, answers are bound to often be very similar.

We've traditionally encouraged people to ignore the fact that there's similar answers already present, and contribute anyway (as long as it's not plagiarism).

One of the reasons is that the presence of multiple answers with subtle differences in wording or structure can be a net plus. Different contributors' ways of putting things may help different groups of people understand the issue.

There's nothing that needs doing here. If a reader can't be bothered to at least skim all the more highly voted answers, it's their loss.

Answer (score 7):

Warning: generalization ahead.

I sometimes envision a certain group of answerers as "trained monkeys". They sit behind their dual-screen setup with Stack Overflow on one, and their LinqPad/[DotNet|JS|SQL]Fiddle/RegexBuddy on their other monitor. They religiously F5 the frontpage, filtered on their favorite tags, and open any question whose title seems even remotely answerable. This group isn't small.

So along with the age-old *"ASCII stupid question, get a stupid ANSI"*, when you ask a trivial question, these hordes of users go and type more or less the same answers at the same time. No explanation given, no drawbacks mentioned, just code and "try this".

Apart from the rep game, it's a byproduct of not wanting to close questions that ask three things at the same time as "too broad", and not wanting to close questions as duplicates because the variable names are different or whatever. Back in the day (you're linking to a four-year-old question) this was fine, because the question was in fact unique, but nowadays it still happens - and even more than before.

It's just that some users see no problem in having their answer out there which states exactly the same as existing answers, and there isn't one - for reasons others have explained here already.

Comment: We refer to this trained group of monkeys as [FGITWers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533). Instead of bananas, they were trained with reputation points. Which don't taste nearly as good, nor have any actual value, making it a fascinating social experiment.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need to handle those. The answers are not plagiarizing from each other or an outside source (as far as we can tell), and for many simple questions involving code its entirely reasonable to believe that 2 people independently come up with exactly the same solution.

There is no need to do anything here.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is for sure: you do not flag for moderator intervention. That is for cases where the community can't handle it but a moderator can; they're not juries and judges so they can't make the call in these cases either - and as you say, there isn't even any kind of wrongdoing to moderate, just a bit of concurrent activity.

If this situation happens however, then I think it is worthwhile to check out the question itself. If equal answers come so easily in the same time frame then they may be fastest gun answers to a beginner question which are likely a duplicate.

Other than that: move along.