# Canonical for ODBC error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: discussion, canonical

One very common question I encounter often is when connecting to a database, people get the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

This is most often a setup issue (driver installed with the wrong bitness, no driver installed at all) or a typo in the driver name. Most of them don't contain a minimal, reproducible example, because users don't provide the bitness of their program nor the ODBC drivers installed on the system and their bitness, and we can't answer them with easy-to-implement code because it's the setup that's wrong.

We have [681 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22Data%20source%20name%20not%20found%22%20is%3aq) currently with that error in it, and I've checked the most voted ones for being a candidate as a canonical. However, I haven't found a good candidate. While some explain the source of the error, most are very specific to a certain ODBC driver and a certain programming language.

Would this be a good subject for writing a new canonical question, agnostic of programming language and database driver, even though there are already many questions?

Or is there a good candidate for a canonical I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be a good subject for writing a new canonical question, agnostic of programming language and database driver, even though there are already many questions?

Yes, **if you can fit a complete answer into a comprehensible amount of text.**

- It looks like a *practical* answer (the one that SO is about) would very much depend on the OS/OS version/specific driver/driver version. I.e. volume-creep and obsolescence-prone stuff like what to download, where to check, what to click.
- So it seems like the best you can do is to

  - outline the general causes and directions
  - link to other questions that consider the specific cases in more detail
  - (optional) rename the questions you're referring to so that it's more clear which niche they cover

**I have doubts if it would be useful to make a directory of other questions covering specific cases** -- because of the aforementioned scope and obsolescence concerns (and because it would duplicate, inefficiently, SO's search functionality). It I were you, **I would instead give ["how to find the solution" -- methods and principles that are expected to stay true for a very long time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338492/should-we-be-teaching-people-to-think-for-themselves/338500#338500)** (e.g. what to download -> which products to generally look at for this component; system settings and dialogs -> what system components and keywords in settings to search) **and frame references as mere examples illustrating that.**

In this case, as new versions are released, your explanations will stay true and helpful. If someone wishes to update the references to those for new versions, fine, but it ceases to be a requirement and thus a maintenance headache!

Comment: I've tried to follow your feedback as best as possible (haven't actually identified any usable questions to refer to). The Q&A is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58571740/7296893), I've made the answer a community wiki and welcome contributions.

Comment: @ErikA very illustrative. +1

Comment: @Erik, I've upvoted your canonical, but I'm tempted to downvote this Meta question on the basis that it's just begging for votes. :-) Seriously, nice job. You don't have to ask permission for every canonical that you want to submit.

Comment: Well, I don't get rep for it (except votes on the question since I can't make that a wiki), so you can't call me the forbidden rep-w-word. If you think this Q&A is truly futile, feel free to downvote or delete it, but it's my first language-agnostic one and I liked having Ivan's input and support too

Comment: I meant more that the Meta question was driving traffic, and thus votes, to the canonical, which actually *can* earn you reputation. But it was a joke. Input and support is what Meta is for, after all. I’m glad this worked out so well. It’s refreshing to see. Regarding wiki status, moderators can set that for questions, but we generally don’t mark the question itself as a wiki, since it isn’t the part that the community maintains, and you deserve whatever rep gains you get, since you’re the one who took the time to put it together initially. @Erik

Comment: AFAICS this question asks for community feedback about an appropriate course of action because the OP was unsure rather than for any kind of "permission". So I don't see anything wrong with it regardless of whether it gained them reputation.